# How many app.config files are you allowed to have per AppDomain?

Tags: .net, configuration

I'm hoping there's a way to avoid custom configuration files if an application runs in a single AppDomain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Suzanne Cook's .NET CLR Notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316034511/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/suzcook/):

> [App.Config Files](https://web.archive.org/web/20140412124712/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/06/02/app-config-files.aspx):
>
> As default  the app config file of the
> default appdomain is in the process
> exe’s directory and named the same as
> the process exe + ".config".  Also,
> note that a web.config file is an
> app.config - ASP.NET sets that as the
> config file for your appdomain.
>
> To change the config file, set an
> AppDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile to
> the new location and pass that
> AppDomainSetup to your call to
> AppDomain.CreateDomain(). Then, run
> all of the code requiring that
> application config from within that
> new appdomain.
>
> Note, though, that you won’t be able
> to choose the CLR version by setting
> the ConfigurationFile – at that point,
> a CLR will already be running, and
> there can only be one per process.
>
> Application configuration files are
> per appdomain. So, you can set a ‘dll
> config’ by using the method above, but
> that means that it will be used for
> the entire appdomain, and it only gets
> one.